# Force editing on DataGridView to one column

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want to only allow editing of one column in my DataGridView, but I want to allow the user to double click on any item in the row, and when the CellBeginEdit fires, force editing of my colum. I started by doing this:

```
Private Sub dgvCaptions_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgvCaptions.CellBeginEdit
        If e.ColumnIndex <> COL_CAPTION Then
            e.Cancel = True
            dgvCaptions.ClearSelection()
            dgvCaptions.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(COL_CAPTION).Selected = True
            dgvCaptions.BeginEdit(False)
        End If
    End Sub
```

But this throws an error in the BeginEdit(False) line because 'Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the BeginEdit function.' which of course it will do, but that is what I want. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found this link to be useful and adapted it for my needs:

```
Delegate Sub SetColumnIndex(ByVal i As Integer)

    Private Sub dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        If Me.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex <> Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            Dim nextindex As Integer = Math.Min(Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1, Me.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1)
            Dim method As New SetColumnIndex(AddressOf Mymethod)
            Me.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(method, nextindex)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Mymethod(ByVal columnIndex As Integer)
        Me.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(columnIndex)
        Me.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
    End Sub
```

[MSDN Forum Credit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/f824fbbf-9d08-4191-98d6-14903801acfc/)

Answer (score 1):

instead of handling `CellBeginEdit` event, try by making other cells readonly and handling `double click` event. In `double click` handler set selected cell to your editable cell and then call `BeginEdit`

Comment: I don't just want to edit on double click though, I want the user to either press F2 or double click on any item in the row and it will allow them to edit just one column in that row